# Branch switching erased my work

Tags: git

I worked, committed and pushed my work in a feature branch `branch1`. Then I created another branch `branch2`. Running `git checkout branch2` erased all my local changes already committed. Is it possible to switch to newly created `branch2` from `branch` without losing work?

Do note code is not merged remotely in `master` yet.

Comment: Could you please share your relevant command history?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @0e1val OSX, the one I am using.

Comment: If code is committed then it should be there when you come back to the same branch or if you created some other branch from that branch

Comment: code comitted remotely on bitbucket in `branch1`. I then created new branch from `master` named `branch2` and did a `git checkout`. It screwed up everything

Comment: @Volatil3 So you committed changes in one branch, and now you're wondering why those changes are not present in an other branch?!

Comment: @Biffen Definitely I am new to git. I am not wondered. Thing is I did blunder. All I want to switch to new branch without losing work, so that new features could be committed to relevant branch.

Comment: @Volatil3 Your latest comment makes little sense to me, but it sounds like you should read a Git tutorial.

Comment: You may find this helpfull when working on a branching workflow https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Branching

Answer (score 5):

`git checkout -b branch3 branch1` will give you a branch named `branch3` which contains all of `branch1`'s changes.

That said, I recommend you read up on git branching before you proceed. git is a powerful tool, and I don't advise using it before coming to understand the fundamentals.

In this case, what you're doing wrong is assuming that one feature you're writing (the stuff on `branch2`) needs another feature (the stuff on `branch1`) present. This in large part defeats the purpose of creating a separate branch to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new branch, use a command

```
git checkout -b branch3
```

The branch3 will contain all the code from the branch where you were currently while running above command. Or you can use

```
git checkout -b branch3 [frombranchName]
```

It seams that you created new branch from some other branch, and now you are looking for the code.

Comment: If there is some thing wrong, please mention it before blindly pressing down vote.